# Program file data not available when running test

Tags: testing

When I try to run my tests with `cargo test-bpf`, I get this error:

```
thread 'processor::tests::it_works' panicked at 'Program file data not available for program_name (...)'
```

This is my test code:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use {
        super::*,
        assert_matches::*,
        solana_program::{
            instruction::{AccountMeta, Instruction},
            system_program::ID as SYSTEM_PROGRAM_ID,
        },
        solana_program_test::*,
        solana_sdk::{
            signature::Signer, sysvar::rent::ID as SYSVAR_RENT_ID, transaction::Transaction, signer::keypair::Keypair
        },
        spl_associated_token_account::{
            get_associated_token_address, instruction::create_associated_token_account,
        },
        spl_token::ID as TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    };

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn it_works() {
        let program_id = Pubkey::new_unique();

        let (mut banks_client, payer, recent_blockhash) = ProgramTest::new(
            "program_name",
            program_id,
            processor!(process_instruction),
        )
        .start()
        .await;

        let test_acct = Keypair::new();

        let mut transaction = Transaction::new_with_payer(
            &[Instruction {
                program_id,
                accounts: vec![
                    AccountMeta::new(payer.pubkey(), true),
                    AccountMeta::new(test_acct.pubkey(), true)
                ],
                data: vec![1, 2, 3],
            }],
            Some(&payer.pubkey()),
        );
        transaction.sign(&[&payer, &test_acct], recent_blockhash);

        assert_matches!(banks_client.process_transaction(transaction).await, Ok(_));

    }
}
```

Comment: What's ProgramTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the right Program Name in this line:

```
   let (mut banks_client, payer, recent_blockhash) = ProgramTest::new(
     "program_name",
     program_id,
     processor!(process_instruction),
   )
```

Probably the correct program name is the name of the file in the  `target/deploy/` folder of your project